# Neo4j, how to index and give ids to node

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I'm kinda new to neo4j, and I want to start building an application with neo4j and nodejs.

From what I understand neo4j adds `id` to each node it creates, and this id should not be use outside the db, So that means if I have users then looking user by id (the same id neo give when created that user) is not that smart.

So the questions are:

1. What will be the best why to look for a user? email? could be, but not every thing in the application has a unique identifier like email for a user
2. I saw few posts writing about `uuid`, lets assume I'm using it.. can i save save that field with name `id`? or i need some other name?
3. Do I need to do something special if I want that field to use as an index? (I want the search by id to be fast.)
4. `uuid` generates a very long string, Isn't that a bit of overhead to index that string? indexing a number is faster, no?
5. if not using `uuid` what you think is other option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Best way - UUID.

2) Yes.

3) No. You just need to add [index](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-schema-index.html) to database. Example:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :User(uuid)
```

4) That's true that `id` lookup is faster, especially in Neo4j (due to storage implementation). However index-backed lookup using UUID performs very well and most of the Neo4j users are using this (if there are no another unique identifier in their domain).

5) UUID is the best option. Especially when you take in account - how to generate ID's in clustered setup. UUID's provides possibility to generate unique identifier without taking any global database locks and etc. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) you can read a bit more theoretic information about UUID's.

---

There are existing Neo4j extensions, which can generate UUID's for you.
For example - [GraphAware/neo4j-uuid](https://github.com/GraphAware/neo4j-uuid).
In this extension you can configure property name, for which nodes/relationships UUID's should be applied and etc.

Comment: Thanks that is a great answer!, I installed that graphAware plugin. and its all working great (every node gets uuid property) but when im querying the database to see all the indexes nothing return.. Im doing `curl  http://localhost:7474/db/data/schema/index/` and i get `[]` any idea why? according to the documentation the put index on the uuid by default.

Comment: @tubu13 I am not sure. But, probably this is another index that is build on top of legacy indexes. You should (and can do it safely) add constraints on desired labels for uuid property. Constraints are better because there also enforce uniqueness.

Comment: constrains are automatically indexed?

Comment: Yeap. Neo4j creates index for each constraint. You can see this in schema after creating constraint.